# Loading of Home taking too long

Tags: cache, nfs, netapp

We have a shared storage from NetApp mounted onto about 80 systems (all running Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit). These days there is some problem with the loading of user homes onto the lab machines (authentication is instantaneous). File Manager takes too long. Desktop items appear after quite long time say 2-3 minutes. Starting Google Chrome shows "building cache..." and it stucks there". Firefox starts but does not open any website.
This behaviour is seen for every 3 out of 5 login attempts, means for the other 2 attempts it works fine. Its not even fixed for a few machines. All are behaving in a similar manner.

Any hints what could be the reason, from where should i start debugging ??

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of your problem, hence why I'm not posting it as an answer, but the classic cause of weird pauses in NFS is that the portmap daemon isn't running on all the clients. If it's not, or if it isn't working properly, then NFS will periodically stop and wait for it, twiddling its thumbs until a timeout occurs. Everything will *work* --- but very, very slowly.

Comment: Hello, there were some machines which were down due to some reason but were serving as nfs servers for sharing some directories and the rcp client was giving timeout error in the log. I pursued the same and figured out that these nfs server mounts were the source of latency.
@David: Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check server load and and server error logs (apache, php) and see what errors there are and also check

To listacizE:

1. Check responses sent and received by your page (using Chrome Debugging tools Ctr+J) or firebug
2. Check server errors to see if any specfic errors are there. eg: APache logs, php logs, mysql logs
3. Also check the server load. If the load is too high, consider load balancing

Comment: I need to bother about server only if the browser request leaves my system and reaches the web server. Browser doesn't load fully at the very first place.

Comment: we need more data. a link would be nice. its just shooting in the dark otherwise